# SASL Error connecting to remote libvirt over SSH: No worthy mechs found

Tags: libvirt, sasl

I have a server running Ovirt Node that I'm trying to manage remotely using libvirt. I have an SSH keypair installed and can `ssh user@server -i ssh-privkey` successfully. When I try to connect to `qemu+ssh//user@host/system?keyfile=ssh-privkey`, I get this error:

> authentication failed: Failed to start SASL negotiation: -4 (SASL(-4): no mechanism available: No worthy mechs found)

That led me down the path of getting TLS keys and certificates installed on the client and the server mostly according to [these instructions](https://wiki.libvirt.org/page/TLSSetup) (the configuration is slightly different because I have only one host and am using Terraform to manage the certificates*). However, I still get the same error. When I look at the output of `libvirt --listen --verbose` on the server when a connection failed, the only useful output is this:

> error : virNetSocketReadWire:1792 : End of file while reading data: Input/output error

I have checked every firewall between the client and the server and they should all be wide open. What else could be the cause of this error?

---

* The goal is ultimately to use Terraform to provision libvirt resources, however I get the same errors trying to connect with `virsh` and `virt-manager`.

---

**UPDATE:** It's easier to connect just via SSH; this question exists because I couldn't figure out how to turn off SASL. It turns out SASL is enabled for SSH connections due to `vdsm` setting `auth_unix_rw="sasl"` in `/etc/libvirt/libvirtd.conf`. Removing that config means I can just use my SSH private key as I intended. The TLS configuration was a wild goose chase that was further hindered by `vdsm` changing the configured location of all the PKI files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're likely missing a RPM package on your client host. First on the virtualization host check `/etc/sasl2/libvirt.conf` and see what 'mech_list' setting is uncommented.

Back on your client you'll need to install a 'cyrus-sasl-XXXX' RPM that provides the same mechanism that the server is set to use. For a modern libvirt install it will probably be using  'cyrus-sasl-scram' for plain username/password auth, but for older installs, it might still be using 'cyrus-sasl-md5'

Comment: My server shows `mech_list: scram-sha-256`. My client is Debian-based and doesn't have a `cyrus-sasl-scram` package. Do you know what is needed in Debian, or do I just need to use a Red Hat based OS? Obviously not ideal but it wouldn't be as inconvenient for me since the client is already in a VM to be Linux at all.

Comment: For inexplicable reasons, Debian put the SCRAM module in the the GSSAPI package libsasl2-modules-gssapi-mit

Comment: That worked, thank you! At least, it works in virt-manager, when I put in a username/password. Is there any way to either not require a SASL username/password, embed it in the connection URI, or embed it in the environment similar to `ssh-agent`? Terraform is failing because it has no mechanism to supply the username/password.

Comment: Looks like making an `auth.conf` file makes this work without entering a username/password in `virt-manager`: https://avdv.github.io/libvirt/auth.html Unfortunately this is not working in Terraform.